# ASP.NET Nested Repeaters handling controls within outer repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two nested repeaters let's say :outer one for posts and inner one for comments .
the outer repeater contains two Divs : one for the inner repeater ,and the other one contains a text box and a button placed to add a comment .

the problem is : when i click on the button it just does not any thing (it must access the database and add the comment ) , i added this events but it does not reach it at all .

```
void btnComment_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= commentRepeater.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == i.ToString())
            {
                TextBox txtComment = (TextBox)commentRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("txtComment");

            }

        }

    }
```

please i need a help with that .

Comment: Put a break-point and see whether you can get past the if statement inside your loop.

Comment: Can you please add the repeater code? The more we can see, the more we can help.

Comment: mr.edocetirwi I can't get past the command itself !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the outer repeater's OnItemCommand value.

```
<asp:Repeater OnItemCommand="btnComment_Command" .... >
```

and the ItemCommand function should look like this (note the parameters are different):

```
void btnComment_Command(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {...}
```

Comment: I had this error :(
does not contain a definition for 'btnComment_Command' and no extension method 'btnComment_Command' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.wallpage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: this is the first line in the outer repeater :
<asp:Repeater ID="postRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="postRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="btnComment_Command">

Comment: I have just added the CommandName property to the btnComment
does it seem to be right ???
 <asp:Button ID="btnComment"   runat="server" Text="Comment" CommandName="btnComment_Command" />

Comment: please i need to know what the comment_button's properties should be ?
remember :comment_button is in the outer repeater .

Comment: When you implemented the above code in my answer, were you able to connect the button with `btnComment_Command`? Try putting a breakpoint in the method and check if it stops when you click a button.